# Magento 2.3 How to apply coupon code discount on regular price

Tags: magento2, php, database, javascript

When I apply a coupon code on the cart, it gives a discount on the final price if a special price is set. But I want to apply a discount on a regular price ( **If a special price is set on that product**) If anyone knows how I can do this then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Have you got any solution on this?